# is there an Emacs org-mode command to jump to an org heading?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, is there a command like org-goto-heading?

In a long org-mode file, I have a heading toward the bottom like this:

```
* questions
```

I'd like to jump to that heading without having to wade through all the other instances of the word `questions`.

Is there a command like:

Basically I would like to navigate to that heading using something like this: `M-x org-goto-heading questions <RET>`

Comment: org-goto is a great way to navigate. However, there no shortcut assigned to it, so in user-config, I set a global key: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'org-goto)` then started using it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an interesting thread from the org mailing list [discussing navigation](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/47452).

Essentially, add this to your init file:

```
(setq org-goto-interface 'outline-path-completion
      org-goto-max-level 10)
```

And you can jump to heading with the `org-goto` command <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd>.
You can also use <kbd>C-u C-c C-w</kbd> `org-refile` by adding this to your
init file:

```
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
```

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this works for you but there is a `org-goto` function `C-c C-j`.

Once you invoke it you can scroll the tree using up and down keys or using a search `C-s`.

Here's a snippet from the [docs](http://orgmode.org/org.html).

```
C-c C-j     (org-goto)

Jump to a different place without changing the current outline visibility.
Shows the document structure in a temporary buffer, where you can use the
following keys to find your destination:

          <TAB>         Cycle visibility.
          <down> / <up>   Next/previous visible headline.
          <RET>         Select this location.
          /           Do a Sparse-tree search
          The following keys work if you turn off org-goto-auto-isearch
          n / p        Next/previous visible headline.
          f / b        Next/previous headline same level.
          u            One level up.
          0-9          Digit argument.
          q            Quit
```

Comment: Such a good reference and definitely one to remember when using large org files!

Answer (score 8):

I have this command bound to `M-o`: `(imenu-anywhere)`.

It allows you to quickly jump to sections (selected from a list of all sections). It does not only work in org-mode, but in many other modes as well.

Answer (score 7):

Then there's [org-occur-goto](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/org-occur-goto.el), which makes a multi-occur search on all your org-mode buffers and displays results dynamically as you type.

Useful for any text (not only headings).

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for headings in agenda files, `helm-org-agenda-files-headings` is a very useful command. It's part of the [`helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) package, available via MELPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple regexp search (`isearch-forward-regexp`) for `"^* questions"`.

I.e. type

> M-x isearch-forward-regexp

Emacs will then prompt you for a string to search (the minibuffer will prompt: "I-search").  You then simply type:

> ^* questions

Comment: please explain and provide an example for what is meant by `isearch-forward-regexp`, so that others who are going through this answer have a better understanding at once without having to google the term and building the regex from scratch